# Strange the rule works for an insertion on PostgreSql 9.5/9.6

Tags: sql, postgresql

example:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
name text
);


ALTER TABLE public.test
ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);


CREATE TABLE public.v_test
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
v_id bigint,
v_name text
);


ALTER TABLE public.v_test
ADD CONSTRAINT v_test_constraint_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert AS
ON INSERT TO test DO INSERT INTO v_test (v_id, v_name)
VALUES (new.id, new.name);
```

then execute

```
insert into test(name)
values 
('1'),
('2'),
('3')
```

values in test.id <> v_test.v_id

Tested on postgresql 9.5/9.6 install from PPA  http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt

OS ubuntu-sever 14.04/16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not the case. That's what said in the Postgresql support

> This is expected behavior, because the rule works like a macro, and
>   you have a volatile argument (that is, the nextval() call for the
>   serial column's default) being passed to it and thereby being executed
>   twice. IOW, what you wrote is equivalent to
>
> insert into test(id, name) values  (nextval('test_id_seq'), '1'),
>   (nextval('test_id_seq'), '2'), (nextval('test_id_seq'), '3');
>
> and that executes, then the rule causes this to also be executed:
>
> insert into v_test (v_id, v_name) values  (nextval('test_id_seq'),
>   '1'), (nextval('test_id_seq'), '2'), (nextval('test_id_seq'), '3');
>
> What you seem to want would be much more reliably done with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see your point - I tested it and I always get into `v_test.v_id` next ID value from sequence. If you try to insert only one new record into `test` table it is more visible. Unfortunately rule cannot reference `old.id` value.